# UI Image picker confusion

Tags: c#, xamarin, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

I'm implementing a UI Image Picker in my Xamarin application and got stumped by a void function used in the code. The function I'm referring to is called OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia()

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhotoPickerService))]
namespace PhotoPickerImplementation.iOS
{
    public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskCompletionSource;
        UIImagePickerController imagePicker;

        public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync()
        {
            //Create and define UIImagePickerController
            imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController
            {
                SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
                MediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.AvailableMediaTypes(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
            };

            //Set Event Handlers
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled += OnImagePickerCancelled;

            //Present UIImagePickerController
            UIWindow window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
            var viewController = window.RootViewController;
            viewController.PresentViewController(imagePicker, true, null);

            //Return Task Object
            taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();
            return taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

        void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
        {
            //assigns var image to the edited image if there is one, otherwise it'll assign it to the original image
            UIImage image = args.EditedImage ?? args.OriginalImage;

            if (image != null)
            {
                //Convert UIImage to .NET stream object
                NSData data;
                if(args.ReferenceUrl.PathExtension.Equals("PNG") || args.ReferenceUrl.PathExtension.Equals("png"))
                {
                    data = image.AsPNG();
                    //Console.WriteLine(data);
                }

                else
                {
                    data = image.AsJPEG(1);
                }

                Stream stream = data.AsStream();

                UnregisterEventHandlers();
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(stream);
            }

            else
            {
                UnregisterEventHandlers();
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }

            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }



        void OnImagePickerCancelled(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            UnregisterEventHandlers();
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }

        void UnregisterEventHandlers()
        {
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia -= OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled -= OnImagePickerCancelled;
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation uses this function and I'm trying to understand it. Why does the function OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia use the local variables data and stream? Since its a void function, the variables stay local to the functions and are never returned outside of the function (or at least I don't see them being returned).

Am I missing something? What value do these variables add to the image picker, and what might be their purpose?

Comment: `stream` is assigned to TaskCompletionSource, so that the calling function can access it

Comment: @Jason but the value of stream is never returned since its a void function, so I'm confused on how the calling function is even accessing that value

Comment: GetImageStreamAsync returns a Task, and the stream is attached to that

Comment: @Jason after taking a break and coming back I reread your first response. I think I'm misunderstanding what TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskCompletionSource even means in my code. Could you break that down for me or by chance point me to a resource? I think I have a knowledge gap about tasks and whatever that taskCompletionSource is

Comment: this is basically a pattern to turn a traditional async operation into one that works with async/await.  You call async method A with await, and it returns a Task.  Then when A's completion handler fires, it assigns its result to the Task that A has already returned.  Then the Tasks completes, and the original caller can continue with the result.

Comment: @Jason I just read about it real quick. What's the benefit of using this pattern in this scenario? Thanks for all the suggestions so far

Comment: it allows you to use async/await, which simplifies the flow of your code as opposed to using a completion handler

Comment: @Jason but why use async/await at all? Can't these just be normal value returning or void functions?

Comment: because **UIImagePickerController** is async and uses a completion handler.  It does not return a value when it completes, it calls a completion handler.

Comment: This is making more sense now. So this line of code right here still confuses me: imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia ... when OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia is called, what value is being added to the other function on the right side? What's happening in that statement?

Comment: The `+=` syntax is how event handlers are assigned.  This is basic C#

Comment: I don't quite understand what's being concatenated though. the code:  imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia; translates over to imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia = imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia + OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia;   so my question is, since OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia is void, what value is actually being assigned to imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia?

Comment: as I noted before, this is **how event handlers are assigned to events**.  This is NOT `x += 1;` it is a completely different use of the `+=` operator.  Just like `+` can be used to add numbers AND concat strings.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code, it uses `data` to "create" the `stream` (`Stream stream = data.AsStream();`) and than this `stream` is set as a result of `taskCompletionSource` which is actually outside the function `taskCompletionSource.SetResult(stream);` this `taskCompletionSource` is finally used by `GetImageStreamAsync` that returns a `Task`, (`return taskCompletionSource.Task;`)

Comment: This makes quite a bit more sense now. I think I have a knowledge gap on what the task  completion source really is. Could you break down what this means: TaskCompletionSource<Stream> taskCompletionSource. Is this a function? what exactly is this?

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource` is a class related to the `Task` class, which allows you to run asynchronous operation (not in the main thread). `Task` can return a value or can just "do stuff" that requires time, so that is necessary to do them in a secondary thread. To be honest, I always used `Task` class directly so I can't give you more information about `TaskCompletionSource` class, but to what I see in documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1) it seems that it allows you to handle tasks in a different way